# How do I get a popover to respect "auto right" when the popover is inside a <td> element?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, jqlite

I have a table where each cell holds a list of links.  I've chosen to only show the first item of the list in the `<td>`, then I created a `badge` and put it next to the `<td>` item.  Clicking on the `badge` generates a `popover` which contains the rest of the items from the list.  Adding, `top|right|left|bottom` works fine, but sometimes the `popover` is cut off by the edge of the browser window depending on where the triggering element is located.  I tried using `auto right` as a way to say, "Hey, if there's no room to open up on the right, then open up on the left", but the "`auto`" class always puts the popover on top of the item in the cell. I've tried adding `data-container="body"` to the trigger element but it doesn't appear to have any effect.  Any ideas on how I can make the "auto" class behave correctly within a table cell?

Also, I'm not using `jquery`.  I'm using `jqlite` provided by the Angular framework, assuming that that information is important to whomever is trying to answer this.

HTML:

```
<span ng-if="something.length > 0">
<span ng-if="something[0].link">
    <a>{{something[0].content}}</a>
    <span ng-if="something.length > 1">
        <a type="button"
           class="btn badge"
           title="Title"
           popover-template="somedirectory/someotherdirectory/somefile.tpl.html"
           data-container="body"
           popover-placement="auto right">
            +{{something.length - 1}}
        </a>
        <span ng-cloak></span>

    </span>
</span>
```

Comment: Since you're using AngularJS, you might consider using [Angular UI Bootstrap](angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/).

Comment: I'm actually using the a forked version of Bootstrap since it offers the ability to pass an html template as the popover content.